# Couldn't bind [Char] with actual type (Maybe a)

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

So I have this:

```
lstDelete :: [Char] -> Lst a -> Lst a
lstDelete k inp@(lstNode key)
    | k == key && lstIsEmpty = Map.delete key (Map.fromList inp)
```

The problem is, k is of type [Char], and key is of type (Maybe a):

```
data Lst a = lstNode (Maybe a)
```

So I'm getting the error saying:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘Maybe a’
```

How can I fix this without changing `lstDelete :: [Char] -> Lst a -> Lst a`? I also want to keep the `Maybe a` since I want it to be able to be empty too.

Comment: Can you describe what the function should do? Like, what would be the output of `lstDelete "foo" (LstNode (Just 42))`?

Comment: What is `Map.delete`? `Map.fromList`? `lstIsEmpty`?

Answer (score 9):

There is several problem with your code:

1. Constructors names should start with capital letter.

```
    data Lst a = LstNode (Maybe a)
```

2. Your list can contain only one value
3. `lstDelete` doesn't make any sense. It accept `[Char]` as key and `Lst a` as list. There is no way to compare them (there is no nontrivial function that can accept those parameters). You should either change type to

```
   lstDelete :: [Char] -> Lst [Char] -> Lst [Char]
```

or write more generic

```
   lstDelete :: Eq a => a -> Lst a -> Lst a
```

4. `Map.fromList` accepts `[(k, v)]`, you can't pass `Lst a` to it.
5. `lstIsEmpty` is not defined.